# Проблемы c API Яндекс-Карт и HTTPS

Tags: yandex-maps-api, ssl, https, яндекс-карты

После перевода сайта на HTTPS перестал подгружаться GeoXML-файл с метками.
ymaps.geoXml.load говорит {status: "500", message: "can't load XML file"}

```
ymaps.geoXml.load("/map/map.xml")
                 .then(function (res) {  
                     myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
                 }, 
                 function (error){
                     console.log(error);         
                 });
```

При том, аналогичная штука здесь https://jsfiddle.net/k0ewduu3/ работает нормально.

Если вернуть HTTP, то все работает отлично.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Смотрите в логи сервера

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил и сам отвечу.
Проблема была в Яндексовском клиенте, который забирает файл с сервера. Без CA-сертификата он отказывается устанавливать HTTPS-соединение. Добавил CA-cert в настройки сервера и все заработало.